# Information never gets lost theory - formalization

Tags: information

From a video I say about information theory, the sentence "Information never gets lost, it is there but in different 'arrangement'"

Meaning that if we burn a toilet paper into ash, we could theoretically recreate that toilet paper if we had enough computing powers and an algorithm that would do so.

What I am trying to say is that even if it is may seem super hard - it is theoretically possible.

- My question is simple, what do we have about this theory? Is it even true? because there are counter-theories that information does get lost.

Also, how do we give "information does not get lost" a mathematical figure?
I would assume it is something along the lines of

$$ \Delta I = 0$$

But I've never seen this kind of equation before nor when I searched the internet.
It sounds reasonable for me, however I am not a scientist, so I would appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conservation of information is based on the postulates of quantum mechanics as they currently stand - that is, assuming no 'objective collapse' mechanism. It can be thought of as a consequence of three theorems in quantum information theory: the no-cloning, no-deletion and no-hiding theorems. However, it can be more simply encapsulated in terms of the von Neumann entropy (entropy is a measure of information)

\begin{equation}
S = - Tr[\rho\log\rho]
\end{equation}

where $Tr$ is the trace operator and $\rho$ is the density matrix of the system. For a *pure state* - i.e. a state described entirely by quantum mechanics - it can be shown that the entropy is zero. Moreover, no unitary evolution of the density matrix can change this fact. Hence

\begin{equation}
\frac{dS}{dt} = 0.
\end{equation}

Of course, this relies on the assumption that there is no 'objective collapse' of a quantum system. If it turns out that quantum mechanics needs to be modified by including a collapse mechanism, then the conservation of information will no longer hold.

The transition to classical physics is modelled by taking the *reduced density matrix* of a system. This is obtained by tracing out the environmental degrees of freedom of a system. The von Neumann entropy is then, in general, no longer zero.

However, the finite entropy of the reduced density matrix is a consequence of the fact that a system has become entangled with its environment. This may be viewed as a transfer of information between system and environment.

To know anything about the world, we need to have information about it. This involves entanglement and a consequent increase in entropy of the reduced density matrix. Whilst reversing this increase at the Universal level may be mathematically possible, it is not likely to be something that we could ever observe, since this would require a transfer of information.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: There is a hidden assumption: that there is a pure state describing the Universe. Do we have any hint about that?

Comment: Yes, this is an assumption. Established quantum theory as it stands posits that any system can be represented by a state vector in an Hilbert state - this would be a pure state. It may be the case that new evidence will suggest that there are limits to the validity of quantum theory. The theorems of quantum information theory, however, follow from the assumption that the postulates of quantum theory are correct. Interestingly, if 'objective collapse' theories are shown to be correct, this would in fact invalid those postulates.

Comment: Ok, but the possibility of a Hilbert space describing the state of the Universe is highly uncertain, at the present state of our knowledge. This is a fact that makes any claim about the conservation of information highly tentative, if not metaphysical.